# .NET fullscreen two monitors

Tags: .net, fullscreen, multiple-monitors

I'm working on a multi-monitor kiosk application that needs to run full-screen on both monitors. I'm using C# and the standard winforms library. I've used a full-screen method for a single monitor with success, but I don't know how to get it full screen on both monitors.

Comment: Most applications that I run on two monitors don't seem to use both screens when being set to full-screen mode. I usually have to resize it by dragging the border across both monitors. I'm guessing there is no "easy" way to do (as in just calling some standard library method).

Comment: The easiest way is to have a graphics card that can stretch the desktop across two monitors so that they represent a single screen.

Comment: maybe take a look at the windows GDI, but it will require you to use C++. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162826(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aye, you need to [stretch it accross two monitors](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/multi-monitor_in_c_.aspx) or use a videocard that can handle that at a driver level.  I know that any recent NVidia cards can do it.